# How do I check for a certain tag in Python NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

I've been trying to check a tag to see if it is an 'NNP' for quite a while.

```
for key in words:
        temp.append(words[key])
        tagger = [key]
        tag = nltk.pos_tag(tagger)
        x = str(tag[0][1].strip())
        print(x is 'NNP')
```

What the code is supposed to be doing is looping through several keys and checking if the tag is NNP. Whenever the tag is, in fact, NNP, my print statement prints out False. I used type(tag[0][1]) to check if it was a str, and yes it is. I also stripped the string, and I decided to use the str function to make sure it was a string. Nothing seems to work. Is there a built in NLTK function I should be using or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing strings, you should always use the `==` operator instead of `is`:

```
print(x == 'NNP')
```

Using `is` compares the identity of the string objects themselves while `==` checks to see if they are equivalent or equal.

For example:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> tag = nltk.pos_tag(['Google'])
>>> tag
[('Google', 'NNP')]
>>> tag[0][1]
'NNP'
>>> tag[0][1] is 'NNP'
False
>>> tag[0][1] == 'NNP'
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idiomatic use of POS tag checking:

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> text = 'Google is a friend of Facebook and Yahoo shouts at Microsoft because Stackoverflow is giving out hats.'
>>> for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)):
...     print word, pos
... 
Google NNP
is VBZ
a DT
friend NN
of IN
Facebook NNP
and CC
Yahoo NNP
shouts NNS
at IN
Microsoft NNP
because IN
Stackoverflow NNP
is VBZ
giving VBG
out RP
hats NNS
. .
>>> for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)):
...     if pos == 'NNP':
...             print word
... 
Google
Facebook
Yahoo
Microsoft
Stackoverflow
```

With list comprehension:

```
>>> [word for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)) if pos == 'NNP']
['Google', 'Facebook', 'Yahoo', 'Microsoft', 'Stackoverflow']
```